# ToolTip for individual item in asp.net dropdown control

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

In my web site I have one asp.net dropdown control. The length of value in the control is too long to display in that control. I can't increase the size of control because of space consistency in my website. It's difficult to the user to see entire value in dropdown to select a correct value.

How to make a tool tip for each item in dropdown control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a "title" property to each item. But I doubt your visitors will notice this rather subtle hint.

```
foreach (ListItem item in YourDropDownList.Items)
{
  item.Attributes.Add("title", "(the long description)");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. could you paste some sample code snippets.

Comment: Sure, did just that a moment ago... :)

Comment: Are you sure? Check the rendered HTML to confirm the attribute is inserted correctly. I don't have IE6 installed, so I can't test it myself, sorry.

Comment: The title is correctly rendered in each option.But dono what's the problem.:(